# Asp.net 5, Dotnet-ef: How to scaffold fully qualified entity/class names to avoid naming conflicts?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Should be a very easy question to answer:  How to get dotnet-ef to scaffold fully qualified Entity names for references?

I have [read the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold) a few times and not come across any parameter that prefixes Entity names.  The output of course is generated, so modifying the output is not an option.

I can use the following command line to scaffold tables as C# POCOs:

```
dotnet-ef --no-build dbcontext scaffold 
  "Server=****;Database=****;User ID=**;Password=**;"
  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
  -o Models/Entities 
  --context-dir Models/Contexts 
  -c MyDbContext --force
  --use-database-names 
  --no-pluralize 
  --no-onconfiguring 
  -t MyTable1 -t MyTable2 -t Version
```

It generates this line which has a reference conflict with System.Version, which I can fix by either prefixing with Entities.Version or removing the System.Version include:

```
public virtual DbSet<Version> Version { get; set; }
```

My error:

```
Error: CS0104 'Version' is an ambiguous reference 
    between 'MyApp.Models.Entities.Version' and 'System.Version'
```

Comment: With EF Core Power Tools you can rename entities

Comment: You can try to use Alias, `using Version = ClentSideDemo2.Models.Version;` ,if you don't want to add prefix to Version or remove the System.Version.

Comment: @yiyi-you dotnet-ef generates and overwrites the .cs files. It does create partial classes. I wonder if adding the `using Version` alias to a separate partial class file would apply to the initial .cs file?